# mqtt scheduler/timer

Tags: mqtt

I am running a few devices in my house to collect data and enable/disable relays. All of the devices are esp8266 nodemcu with

- pir sensor
- 5v relays
- sensors

and send over mqtt the data to a RPI that hosts the mqtt broker. Currently i am using Freeboard to present the data (temperature, humidity, relay status/control).
i would like to create a scheduler/timer when to enable/disable devices. For example switch on the relay named front_yard at 20:00 and switch it off at 07:30, every day.
Is there a way to create a set of schedules to serve settings like the aforementioned, please? I would prefer a graphical way to do it, if possible, please.

Comment: it is unclear what you actually want to know ... your current question, `Is there a way to create a set of schedules to serve settings like the aforementioned, please?`, has a simple `yes, there is a way` answer ... if that answer is not sufficient, then please update your post with a description of what you have tried, a description of the problems you encountered and ask a specific, answerable question about the problem

Comment: i would like to know the way to create a timer and send through mqtt to some devices.